# "Unknown column in 'field list' "

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a wierd bug in my php code and every time I put a value it throws me an error which says that the first value doesnt exist...
The first value I insert to the database ($from) is the value that is in the error.
I tried to change places with other values but everytime the first value had an error. 
Is it a problem with my code?

```
<?php 
$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
$time = new DateTime();
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","encrypchat");
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$check="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$to'";
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $data[0];
echo "<br />";
if($data[0] >= 1) {
    echo "<br />"."USER EXISTS";
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$to."_msgs (`from_user`, `to_user`, `message`,`time`)
    VALUES (`$from`, `$to`, `$message`,`$time`)";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";

}
if(!$data[0]){
    echo "<br />"."USER DOESNT EXIST";
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You are wide open to mysql injection attacks... use prepared statements plz. Oh, and each user gets his own table? Seriously? just use a relational _"messages"_ table

Comment: Please provide the db creation.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable **as hell** to SQL injection attack, learn how to use prepared statements.

Comment: Do you really have from and to in your URL?

Comment: @LoganWayne not just that, he also has the whole message in the URL

Comment: Oh. That's a long URL, my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove backtics and use single quote in value list like

```
$sql="INSERT INTO ".$to."_msgs (`from_user`, `to_user`, `message`,`time`)
    VALUES ('$from', '$to', '$message','$time')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
VALUES (`$from`, `$to`, `$message`,`$time`)";
```

these should be apostrophes, not back-ticks, which denote table or column-names.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your *GET variables* have values in them.

You use *backticks (`)* in your variables inside the insert query, which should be *single quote (')*

Escape the string of the values of your variables before using them into your queries to avoid some of *SQL injections*.

I'm also advising you to use **POST** method, and not **GET** method if you're having too many variables to pass on.

```
<?php 

/* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","encrypchat");
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

/* USE MYSQLI_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING IN YOUR VARIABLES */

$from = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['from']);
$to = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['to']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['message']);
$time = new DateTime();
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$check="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$to'";
$rs = mysqli_query($con,$check); /* EXECUTE QUERY */

/* YOU CAN ALSO DIRECTLY USE IT TO $data=mysqli_num_rows($rs); AND USE $data IN YOUR CONDITIONS INSTEAD OF $data[0] */
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs,MYSQLI_NUM); 
echo $data[0];
echo "<br />";

if($data[0] >= 1) { /* IF A RECORD HAS BEEN FOUND */

    echo "<br />"."USER EXISTS";
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$to."_msgs (`from_user`, `to_user`, `message`,`time`)
    VALUES ('$from', '$to', '$message','$time')"; /* YOU CAN USE BACKTICKS ON THE COLUMN NAME, BUT NOT FOR THE VARIABLES TO BE INSERTED */

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) { /* IF QUERY FAILED */
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";

}

else if(!$data[0]){ /* MADE IT INTO ELSE IF INSTEAD OF IF ONLY */
    echo "<br />"."USER DOESNT EXIST";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```